# Which Python Cloud Storage lib/API is "officially" supported by Google?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm migrating a Python service out of Google App Engine over to GCE/GKE and could use some help identifying the current production-grade, SLA'd method for managing objects in Google Cloud Storage.

The one referenced by most of [Google's storage docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) is the `google.cloud.storage` library. This looks nice and simple. However, as of now -- Jan 2017 -- there's a big header at the top that identifies the library as **Beta**, and has no SLA or deprecation policy. I'd prefer to use an SLA'd service.

After a lot of searching I found this alternative JSON API example:
    https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-file-transfer-json-python
but it's much more cumbersome and isn't clear that it's better supported.

Any advice on which API to use?
Or better examples for bootstrapping?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage, the service, is not in beta. It has an SLA and a deprecation policy. The client library you've found, the [Google Cloud Client Library for Python (google-cloud)](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/), is in beta, which means that it's possible that a future version of it might in some cases make backwards-incompatible changes. However, it's also the current gold standard for easiest-to-use client library.

I recommend you use that one. Another option is the [Google Python API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/), which is not in beta, but I found the [Google Cloud Client Library for Python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) to be substantially easier to use, which is important.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. That confirms what I was seeing as well.